# sql : show data with condition in another table

Tags: sql, database, exists

i have a schema like this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/690e8

i want to show TransactionID and TransactionDate (with format 'yyyy.MM.dd') where MedicineTypeName not a 'Syrup' and MedicinePrice greater than 15000 using convert, exists, and in...

the result should be like this

[result pics](http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/6512/byw1.png)

i have tried :

```
select th.TransactionID,convert(varchar,th.TransactionDate,20)[tanggal]
from TransactionHeader th 
join TransactionDetail td on th.TransactionID = td.TransactionID 
where td.MedicineID  in 
(
select md.MedicineID
from MsMedicine md join MsMedicineType mmt on mmt.MedicineTypeID = d.MedicineTypeID
where mmt.MedicineTypeName not like 'syrup' and md.MedicinePrice > 15000

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed d.MedicineTypeID to md.MedicineTypeID

Added distinct to prevent dups

```
select distinct th.TransactionID,convert(varchar,th.TransactionDate,20)[tanggal]
from TransactionHeader th 
join TransactionDetail td on th.TransactionID = td.TransactionID 
where td.MedicineID  in 
(
select md.MedicineID
from MsMedicine md join MsMedicineType mmt on mmt.MedicineTypeID = md.MedicineTypeID
where mmt.MedicineTypeName not like 'syrup' and md.MedicinePrice > 15000

)
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/690e8/3)